# How to add up wins/ties/losses using returns (in a game rock/paper/scissors)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to create a game of rock, paper, scissors that has multiple rounds and counts the number of wins/losses/ties within it and I think I have most if it down but I'm having trouble with counting up the number of losses/wins/ties within the loop.

I think what I'm supposed to do is include a "return" statement here but I'm not sure how to approach it and I've tried looking at other examples and I'm still not sure how it works so the returns I have in my code right now just shows where I think it should be.

I feel like I should have a +1 in those areas as well but again, I'm unsure how to approach this.

I cut out **my_choice == scissors** and **my_choice == paper** because I think the whole wins/ties/losses business works the same way as it does for **my_choice == rock**

```
import random

rounds = eval(input("Enter the number of rounds: "))

comp_pack = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

my_pack = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]


for i in range (rounds):


    count_win = ""
    count_losses = ""
    count_ties = ""

    my_choice = input("Enter rock, paper, or sissors: ")

    comp_choice = comp_pack[random.randint(0, len(comp_pack)-1)]

    if my_choice == comp_choice:
        print("tie")
        return count_ties

    elif my_choice == "rock":

        if comp_choice == "paper":
            print("paper covers rock loser")
            return count_losses

        elif comp_choice == "scissors":
            print("rock smashes scissors winner")
            return count_wins

print(count_losses)
print(count_wins)
print(count_ties)
```

Comment: You cant return if you arent in a function. Just keep a count of wins, losses and ties. Increment the appropriate variable after each round.

Comment: For your computer choice, you could just do `random.choice(comp_pack)`. Also you needn't replicate the item names for both user and computer.

Answer (score 2):

Pull your counter variables out of the for loop and increment appropriately using `+= 1`depending on win/loss/tie:

```
import random

rounds = eval(input("Enter the number of rounds: "))
comp_pack = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
my_pack = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

count_wins = 0
count_losses = 0
count_ties = 0

for i in range (rounds):

    my_choice = input("Enter rock, paper, or sissors: ")

    comp_choice = comp_pack[random.randint(0, len(comp_pack)-1)]

    if my_choice == comp_choice:
        print("tie")
        count_ties += 1

    elif my_choice == "rock":

        if comp_choice == "paper":
            print("paper covers rock loser")
            count_losses += 1

        elif comp_choice == "scissors":
            print("rock smashes scissors winner")
            count_wins +=1

print(count_losses)
print(count_wins)
print(count_ties)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement is only for function.
So, if you want to use 'return' statement, you have to make function.
I hope my code could help you.

```
import random

def game(round):
    count_wins = 0
    count_losses = 0
    count_ties = 0

    for i in range(round):
        # I just defined r, c, p in number.
        pack = {"scissors": 1, "rock": 2, "paper": 3}
        my_choice = pack[input("Enter rock, paper, or scissors: ")]
        comp_choice = random.randint(1, len(pack))
        if my_choice == comp_choice:
            print("tie")
            count_ties += 1
        elif comp_choice - my_choice == 1 or comp_choice - my_choice == -1:
            if comp_choice < my_choice:
                # I defined r, c, p in number because of this compare algorithm. I will explain about this at bottom. And I omitted some messages like "paper covers rock", if you want, you can define message dictionary and print here.
                print("win")
                count_wins += 1
            else:
                print("lose")
                count_losses += 1
        else:
            if comp_choice < my_choice:
                print("lose")
                count_losses += 1
            else:
                print("win")
                count_wins += 1
    return count_wins, count_losses, count_ties

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # You can use function game like this.
    game_result = game(3)
    print("Win: %d" % game_result[0])
    print("Lose: %d" % game_result[1])
    print("Tie: %d" % game_result[2])
```

This is detailed explain about algorithm which i used in my code.

Scissor: 1, Rock: 2, Paper: 3

If number is same => TIE

If |comp - my| is 1:
 Big number wins => Rock(2) wins Scissors(1), Paper(3) wins Rock(2)

If |comp - my| is 2:
 Big number loses => Scissors(1) wins Paper(3)

Answer (score 0):

The spacing might be weird from copy/pasting but this is essentially the final result:

```
import random

   def winner(comp_pack):
   my_choice = input("Enter rock, paper, or scissors: ")

   comp_choice = comp_pack[random.randint(0, len(comp_pack)-1)]

        if my_choice == comp_choice:
            print("tie")
            return "tie"

        elif my_choice == "rock":

        if comp_choice == "paper":
            print("paper covers rock, computer wins!")
            return "comp"

        elif comp_choice == "scissors":
            print("rock smashes, scissors winner")
            return "user"

        elif my_choice == "paper":

        if comp_choice == "scissors":
             print("scissors cut paper, computer wins!")
             return "comp"

        elif comp_choice == "rock":
            print("paper covers rock, you win!")
            return "user"

        elif my_choice == "scissors":

        if comp_choice == "paper":
            print("scissors cut paper, you win!")
            return "user"

        elif comp_choice == "rock":
            print("rock smashes paper, computer wins!")
            return "comp"

def main():

   rounds = eval(input("Enter the number of rounds: "))

   comp_pack = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

   i_win = 0
   comp_win = 0
   tie = 0

    for i in range (rounds):
       result = winner(comp_pack)
        if result == "user":
            i_win += 1
        elif result == "comp":
            comp_win += 1
        elif result == "tie":
             tie += 1
        print ("current score: user ", i_win , ", computer ", comp_win)

    if i_win > comp_win:
        print("You win!")
    elif i_win < comp_win:
        print("You lose!")
    else:
        print("Tie!")

main()
```

Comment: To properly paste your code, just copy+paste it here, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to have it indented for you.  Pasting code with obvious syntax errors seems rather pointless.

Comment: Defining the "pack" outside of the function, but then hard-coding the pack's member names inside the function seems like poor division of labor.  Ideally, you want to completely encapsulate the function's internals from its caller.

Comment: The big ugly nested if-then-else is a hint that perhaps you should think about ways to reduce the amount of repetitive code.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself and maybe think about ways to represent knowledge in a data structure or as objects.